# Retrieve results after bulk_save_objects in Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful, marshmallow

I want to bulk save objects in my database in order to improve performance, but I need to get the just inserted items in order to return the created ids, timestamps and more.

I'm using

> session.bulk_save_objects(list_of_models_instances)

And it inserts the data in db, but I need to acces the just created items.

The last approach was to save one by one and then use Marshmallow to dump them, but it doesn't work with many objects

```
session.add(email)
session.flush()
session.refresh(email)
email_schema = EmailSchema()
return email_schema.dump(email)
```

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: The database I'm using is Postgresql